# zenity throws glibc error

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.10, zenity

I have been trying use zenity with standard re-direction in a shell script, something like

**for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $i; done | zenity --list --column ="Number"**

But on the command line this works , but throws the following warning:

(zenity:3328): GLib-WARNING **: Invalid file descriptor.

This seems to happen only when data is redirected to the Zenity command through a pipe.

Could anyone please tell me what this warning signifies?

Comment: Please note that I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is triggered by attempting to close stdin twice - once after all the data has been read from the sequence, and then secondly as it's just about to quit - this is in the zenity source. It's purely cosmetic and can be safely ignored - the zenity code is doing nothing else except quitting at that point.

In the handler `zenity_tree_handle_stdin`, towards the end of the routine it closes the same channel (there is variable hiding caused by using the same named variable in the function and at the global scope):

```
if ((condition != G_IO_IN) && (condition != G_IO_IN + G_IO_HUP)) {
  g_io_channel_shutdown (channel, TRUE, NULL);
  return FALSE;
}
```

In `tree.c` ~line 648 as the program is about to exit:

```
  if (channel != NULL)
    g_io_channel_shutdown (channel, TRUE, NULL);
```

Both of these code paths will attempt to close the same channel, causing the warning. Because the next thing done after line 648 is to issue a `gtk_main_quit`, then I think the warning can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thanks Petesh, I also think that the warning can be safely ignored. The curious fact here is that the warning is found only in certain diastros of Linux, for example it does not seem to happen on Fedora. T

Comment: It Seems zenity is built from different code bases for different distributions of Linux.